# Responsive image - Different images on different screen size

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive

Hi community and thanks in advance for your help.
My problem is following, I would like to display some images while on computer screen but switch those images to only one composite image on mobile devices. Here is the code I have:

```css
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .hidden_mobile {
        display:none;
        background-image: url("http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Mobile-version.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-1">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/top100.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto 15px" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/WW-1.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto 15px" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/fearless.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto 15px" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/bowp-300-1.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto 15px" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ispwp.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto 15px" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
</div>
```

So far it works on computer but on mobile it doesn't. It just displays the images on top of each others.

Thank you

Comment: Use the Javascript/CSS/HTML snippet function so that we can see your code running.

Comment: Hi Victoria, thanks for answering, I didn't know I could do that.This is done now.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here:

1) The elements that you are trying to hide in mobile have an inline `display:block` that overrides the `display:none` in your stylesheet. That's why you keep seeing the images in mobile. In the running snippet below, I removed all the inline styles, and moved the margins to a class in the stylesheet. 
You can read more about CSS rule specificity here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

2) Even if you delete the inline styles, you wouldn't see the background image you want, because you added it to an element that had `display:none`. You need to add that background image to a different element, which I created in the div with class `.mobile_only`.

With these 2 changes, applied in the snippet below, you can see the different images depending on the resolution of your screen.

```css
.hidden_mobile {
height: auto; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto 15px; 
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .hidden_mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile_only {
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url("http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Mobile-version.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/top100.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/WW-1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/fearless.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/bowp-300-1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <img class="hidden_mobile" src="http://julienleveau.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ispwp.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
</div>
   <div class="mobile_only"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is one remaining problem though is that there is a big white space before the background image. Do you know what causes it?

Comment: @Arcencielstudio I don't see it happen in the snippet. Can you post more of your code to see what else could be affecting it?

Comment: Hi Victoria, of course. You can see it live on my homepage http://julienleveau.com

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the slider in the carousel. Did you fix it? If not, does this happen in a specific browser or resolution?

Comment: Hi Victoria, I managed to fix it by applying the hidden-mobile class to the other columns of my row. Those were the one doing the space. Thank you for your big help, you're awesome!